# Why does Navigation Controller disappear when Paper-Onboarding is launched upon app installation?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have this app that requires to have `OnboardingVC` which provides tutorials for the users. The `OnboardingVC`is launched upon app installation. I added my code inside `appdelegate` which consist of code below:

```
 `if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didSee") {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didSee")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnBoardingVC")
        self.window?.rootViewController = mainController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }`
```

When I tapped the `Skip` and `Get Started` buttons inside `OnboardingVC` to proceed to the `MainViewController`, the `Navigation Bar` disappears as well as with the other `ViewControllers`. But when I tapped the `Login` Button inside `MainViewController` the `Navigation Bar` works smoothly. Below are screenshot of my storyboard

[image]

Hope I did explain it in a way you can understand my issue. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Hello is your issue solved with UINavigaitonController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this
as your app always start with a navigation controller

```
if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didSee") {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didSee")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnBoardingVC")
        let nav1 = UINavigationController()
        nav1.viewControllers = [mainController] //Set on board vc as rootviewcontroller
        self.window?.rootViewController = nav1
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }`
```